# Why does 'rails destroy controller ...' not delete the routes created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Just new to rails and so wondering this. Is there a particular reason why this is a case? Would I have to manually delete the routes created everytime?

I find it odd.

For example I did this:

```
$ bin/rails generate controller Articles index
      create  app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
       route  get 'articles/index'
      invoke  erb
      create    app/views/articles
      create    app/views/articles/index.html.erb
      invoke  test_unit
      create    test/controllers/articles_controller_test.rb
      invoke  helper
      create    app/helpers/articles_helper.rb
      invoke    test_unit
```

then this

```
$ rails destroy controller Articles
      remove  app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
      invoke  erb
      remove    app/views/articles
      invoke  test_unit
      remove    test/controllers/articles_controller_test.rb
      invoke  helper
      remove    app/helpers/articles_helper.rb
      invoke    test_unit
```

But the route created isn't deleted
routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'articles/index'
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  # root "articles#index"
end
```

Comment: Works for me, which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: @smathy I checked behaviour in Rails 7.0.6, it behaves as Sammyul reports

Comment: @smathy I'm using Rails 7.0.6 like Les Nightingill

Comment: Oh nevermind, I misread the destroy he was using :) Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Because route generator only gets invoked when you specify actions:
*https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.6/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/controller/controller_generator.rb#L18*

```bash
# only creates a controller, no route
$ bin/rails g controller Articles

# does it in "reverse"
$ bin/rails d controller Articles
```

```bash
# creates a controller and runs route generator
$ bin/rails g controller Articles index

# does it in "reverse", including the route generator
$ bin/rails d controller Articles index
      remove  app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
       route  get 'articles/index'
...
```

Comment: hmmm yes evidently this is how it works... but it seems to violate the "principle of least surprise"! There doesn't seem to be any merit in leaving a route after the controller is removed. Maybe there's a rationale that I'm missing?

Comment: I'm wondering that too. It's a small thing to worry about anyways...